# Python Tkinter: Adding widgets to file dialogs

Tags: python, tkinter, filedialog

I am using `Tkinter` with `Python 2.6` and `2.7` for programming graphic user interfaces.

These User Interfaces contain dialogs for opening files and saving data from the `tkFileDialog` module. I would like to adapt the dialogs and add some further entry widgets e.g. for letting the user leave comments.

Is there any way for doing so?

It seems that the file dialogs are taken directly from the operating system. In `Tkinter` they are derived from the Dialog class in the `tkCommonDialog` module and call the `tk.call("tk_getSaveFile")` method of a frame widget (in this case for saving data).

I could not find out where this method is defined.

Comment: If all else fails you could create your own file dialog with Tkinter/ttk using a Toplevel window, [ttk.Treeview](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/ttk-Treeview.html), Button, ttk.Combobox and the OS module.

Answer (score 4):

`call` method is defined in [`_tkinter.c`](http://fossies.org/dox/Python-2.7.3/__tkinter_8c_source.html#l01325), but there is nothing interesting for your particular task there. It just calls a Tcl command, and the command `tk_getSaveFile` does all the work.

And yes, when there *is* a native file dialog on the operating system, `tk_getSaveFile` uses them (e.g. `GetSaveFileName` is used on Windows). It could be possible to add widgets there, but not without tampering with C sources of Tk. If you're sure that *your* target uses non-native Tk dialogs, you could add something to its widget hierarchy by hacking `::tk::dialog::file::` procedure from Tk (see `library/tkfbox.tcl`).

I would rather take an [alternative implementation of tk_getSaveFile](http://wiki.tcl.tk/15897), written in pure Tcl/Tk and never using the OS facility. This way, we can be sure that its layout is the same for all OSes, and it won't suddenly change with a new version of Tk. It's still far from trivial to provide a convenient API for python around it, but at least, it is possible.

Comment: Thank you for the reference to `tkfbox.tcl`. I will try it that way first. If that does not work I will choose the `FileDialog` instead of the `TkFileDialog` module.

Answer (score 1):

I had to get rid of the canvasx/y statements. That line now simply reads `set item [$data(canvas) find closest $x $y]`, which works well. `$data(canvas) canvasx $x` for its own works well but not in connection with `find closest`, neither if it is written in two lines.