# How to update Tcl/Tk in Python?

Tags: python, tkinter, tcl, tk-toolkit

Tcl and Tk in their version `8.6` have been out now for about six weeks. However, the files that can be downloaded from [Tcl](http://www.tcl.tk) have a different folder structure and lack some files such as `tk85.lib` (or `tk86.lib` now) compared to the Tcl folder in Python.

My question is: How can Tcl and Tk be updated to 8.6 in Python (including the integration into Tkinter)?

The Python version is 2.7 and the operating system is Windows 7.

Comment: You need to recompile the `_tkinter` module. But there isn't much point in doing so because you would need to update the `Tkinter` module to wrap the latest additions. Consider at least reporting this at `bugs.python.org` as a feature request.

Comment: The parts of Tk that Tkinter uses haven't changed very much; I'd expect it to almost be a drop-in replacement. OTOH, source distributions don't include pre-built libraries for any platform. (Obviously.) You'll need a built version.

Comment: @DonalFellows I didn't say it would fail after the person recompiles the module, just that the new functionality wouldn't be nicely available, thus "there isn't much point in doing" the drop-in replacement. Nevertheless, it does look like someone had trouble with Tkinter after the update: http://bugs.python.org/issue16809

Comment: At the moment I am having trouble with Tk 8.5, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14686543/python-tkinter-adding-widgets-to-file-dialogs. I just need an update of the file dialogs, which seem to be coded quite differently in 8.6. Thus, I will try what you suggested.

Comment: @user1485853: Switching tools is usually a substantial undertaking, since tool use means knowledge and effort investment. In most cases, people use tool X because they prefer it to other tools (which means they're not interested in switching) or because the environment they work in simply requires X (which means they can't switch). It's seldom the case that they use tool X because they've never heard of tool Y. While a question like "Is there any possibility to use PyQt instead of Tk?" is ok and may turn out to be helpful, the kind of comment you just made is unhelpful and borders on rudeness.

Answer (score 3):

I'm thinking you should report a bug and hope the next 2.7 release will

1. Exist
2. Be linked against the new version of Tk

(Assuming you have any real reason to want the new version in the first place, that is.)