# Chosing a directory while using askopenfilename interface in Python 3.3

Tags: user-interface, python-3.x, tkinter, filedialog

I want to choose a directory(folder) while using the askopenfilename interface, because I think the interface of askopenfilename is more convenient and more clear for users to choose. Could anybody help me figure out? 
[askdirectory interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yaimx.png)
[askopenfilename interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qxYcU.png)

```
from tkinter import filedialog

filename = filedialog.askopenfilename()  # preferred interface, but I can't choose a folder
directoryname = filedialog.askdirectory()
print(filename)
print(directoryname)
```

Comment: There's nothing to figure out. `askopenfilename` is for picking files. If you need to pick directories your only choice is `askdirectory` or make your own dialog.

Comment: what do you mean by making my own dialog?

Comment: I think what Bryan meant is explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36224235/how-can-i-use-the-same-dialog-box-in-tkinter-to-browse-and-select-files-and-dire