# How to disable "D_Lib" info/warning message during tkinter app execution?

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, tkinter, pyinstaller

I am developing a python tkinter application using `PyCharm 2017.1.2 Community Edition` and package the SW with `pyinstaller 3.2.1`.

During application run-time, from time to time (didn't find the root cause event yet) i get this info/warning messages into the running console.

```
D_Lib: debug printing for files [.*] and level [100] is turned on
D_Lib: debug printing for files [.*] and level [200] is turned on
D_Lib: debug printing for files [.*] and level [300] is turned on
17004:vf_shex.cpp(84): INFO: DllCanUnloadNow returned S_OK.
```

This can be seen within `PyCharm` console (Both in Debug and Run modes), and while executing the `pyinstaller` exe file, at the windows cmd shell.

How to remove/disable these lines?

**EDIT**

I've read the [error when calling QtGui.QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32056783) post - it identifies ViewFinity agent SW installation as prime suspect for changing default dialogs behavior. While ViewFinity agent is indeed installed on my machine, i can't remove it (IT restriction).

Is there a way to disable the usage of Native dialog box (as suggested in the other post for `Qt`) in `tkinter`? (i couldn't find such)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [error when calling QtGui.QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32056783/error-when-calling-qtgui-qfiledialog-getexistingdirectory)

Comment: @eijen: while that post gives some clue, i am not using `Qt` package whatsoever... i'm using `tkinter` for the GUI framework...

Comment: Read the answer. The problem has nothing to do with `Qt`, but something called `Viewfinity`.

Comment: Hello, Googler! ViewFinity is now CyberArk, and one of their products (triggering this issue) seems to be CyberArk Endpoint Privilege Manager. The same issue appears in the R language, by the way: https://stackoverflow.com/q/65190448

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I presume you're opening a file in `Tkinter`? According to this [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14686543/python-tkinter-adding-widgets-to-file-dialogs), `Tkinter` will natively use the file dialogs of the system if they're available:

> when there is a native file dialog on the operating system, `tk_getSaveFile` uses them (e.g. `GetSaveFileName` is used on Windows). It could be possible to add widgets there, but not without tampering with C sources of Tk.

But `Viewfinity` alters those native file dialogs according to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32056783/error-when-calling-qtgui-qfiledialog-getexistingdirectory).

Unless you can come up with some other way of accessing files that isn't through `Tkinter`'s `tkFileDialog` in your application, you're stuck having those info/warning messages on your system when the app is run there.