# How to make this code to take multiple yaml input files and convert them to .json and save all of them to specified path

Tags: python, json, yaml

```
def convert():             #function to convert .yaml to .json 

    in_file = filepath     #assigning input file from GUI to variable
    out_file = savepath    #assigning output path from GUI to variable 
    yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML(typ='safe')
    with open(in_file ) as i:       #opening yaml file 
        data = yaml.load(i)
    with open(out_file, 'w') as o:  #writing json file
        json.dump(data, o, indent=2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is not formatted properly. But let's say your code looks like:

```
def convert():
    in_file = filepath     #assigning input file from GUI to variable
    out_file = savepath    #assigning output path from GUI to variable 
    yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML(typ='safe')
    with open(in_file ) as i:       #opening yaml file 
        data = yaml.load(i)
    with open(out_file, 'w') as o:  #writing json file
        json.dump(data, o, indent=2)
```

You must change some logic here:

1. You must get file name**s** information instead of file name. It can be a list of paths which can be got from `glob`. Then you can get individual file name looping in files.
2. Since you have multiple files you cannot provide 1 file name and save all your files with same name. The best I can think of is (Let's say you are converting yaml files to json files) you can replace the extension of the file and save it with the same name.

### Getting file names:

> The `glob` module finds all the pathnames matching a specified pattern
> according to the rules used by the Unix shell, although results are
> returned in arbitrary order.

see [glob](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html)

Now let's use it:

```
from glob import glob
files = glob("/your/path/*.yaml")

for file in files:
    print(files)
```

Here file is path for each yaml file. Now you can open/use that file name inside the loop and do whatever you want.

### Saving files

To save the file as json you can:

1. Add .json to the file name

Basically use + or fstrings to add .json.

```
json_file_name = file + ".json"
```

or

```
json_file_name = f"{file}.json"
```

Be aware that your file names might look weird. Because you will have `my_file.yaml` changes to `my_file.yaml.json`.

2. Replace yaml with json

Since file paths are strings you can use `replace` method and replace the file name.

```
json_file_name = file.replace("yaml", "json")
```

Here your file name would look better but it will change all `yaml`s in the name. So if your file name has yaml in it it will be changed as well.

Like `my_yaml_file.yaml` changes to `my_json_file.json`.

Comment: Here is my code if more clarification is needed---https://github.com/saurabhkingp/school_management/blob/main/test.py

Comment: Ok, so I used filedialog.askdirectory() to get the path from GUI to a variable but when i am using that variable to pass inside glob like this--                                                      files = glob("filepath/*.yaml")
for file in files:
    print(files)     it is giving me error D_Lib: debug printing for files [.*] and level [100] is turned on
D_Lib: debug printing for files [.*] and level [200] is turned on
D_Lib: debug printing for files [.*] and level [300] is turned on
20496:.../engine/vf_shex/vf_shex.cpp(91): INFO: DllCanUnloadNow returned S_OK.    
What to do now?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/43980056/2681662

Comment: Yes that helped, I think it's just a warning

Comment: Now when I am using                                                                                                     def open_file():
    global filepath
    filepath=filedialog.askdirectory(title="Select a Directory")
    files = glob("filepath/*.yaml")
    for file in files:
        print(files)     <---it prints nothing and when I print files outside for loop then it prints an Empty List. It gives the desired output i.e. C/some/folder/some.yaml into list when I give the path manually i.e. files = glob("C/some/my/path/*.yaml"). Can you tell like how to do that. That'll be great help

Comment: I want to take path from user using tkinter GUI filedialog method

Comment: You're providing a string (literally) as a path to glob: `glob("filepath/*.yaml")`. Here the `"filepath"` is a string not the value of the variable `filepath`. It's not what you want. You have to join your filepath (wich is a variable) to `"*.yaml"`. Here how it had to be: `glob(filepath + "/*.yaml")`or a better version: `glob(os.path.join(filepath, "*.yaml"))`. With the second approach you will have no issue with different operating systems. However you must import the `os` first.

Comment: Thanks, it worked perfectly the way I wanted to.